# Leaflet DWITHIN cql_filter

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet

I have successfully got my cql_filter button to respond correctly in terms of filtering a WMS contour dataset served from PostGIS and GeoServer.

However, my next goal is to complete a cql_filter which filters data within a set distance of the defined object. In my case, I am trying to select all Electrical Pylons within a distance of a defined electrical pylon. Therefore, the Pylon would need to be defined by the user and also the search distance.

I understand that I should be using the 'DWITHIN' query and have again previously completed this in OpenLayers 3 but can't get my code to respond in Leaflet.

My java-script code is:

```
    //Pylon Search Button
    function updatePylons() {
    var pylonfilter = 'DWITHIN(geom, 
      collectGeometries(queryCollection(
        \'Inyaninga_243-198:proposed_pylons_3857\',\'geom\',\'id = \'\'' + document.getElementById('Pylon').value + '\'\' \')), '
        + document.getElementById('distance').value + ', meters)' ;
    return pylons.setParams({CQL_FILTER: pylonfilter});
    };
```

This will be passed to an input form with two fields:

```
    <form>
    Pylons:<br>
          <input type="text" id="Pylon">
          <input type="number" id="distance">
          <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="updatePylons()">
    </form>
```

I have adapted my code as best I can, I'm sure its a minor issue.

Comment: please show us what is being sent to the server

Answer (score 1):

That's because "**DWITHIN**" **cql_filter** does not work when **geom** is in *Degree* and distance is in *metric*. They have to be both on a **projected** **CRS**. It should be a bug in geoserver i think...
Anyway the best thing you can do is to recreate a polygon from the circle. Below i'm posting a solution for this problem using Leaflet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145205/writing-a-function-to-convert-a-circle-to-a-polygon-using-leaflet-js

Comment: `Also, the question is about OL3, not leaflet.` @BradHards the title is `Leaflet DWITHIN cql_filter`  The OP can do it in OpenLayers not Leaflet